# How to create a .desktop unity launcher that starts an executable in a specific working directory

Tags: launcher

Well the whole question is in the title. Say I have the following launcher

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=Lantern
Comment=Lantern interface to ICC
Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar /home/john/local/lantern-chess/lantern.jar
Icon=/
```

how do I make it run in the `/home/john/local/lantern-chess/` folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a line

```
Path=/home/john/local/lantern-chess/
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I had worked this out but askubuntu wouldn't let me answer my own question!

Comment: This only works for me when single clicking from Menu, but not when launching from Nemo. From Nemo it appears to ignore the Path line