# How to make a .desktop file work on Ubuntu 22.04 where the executable file has a dependency on a folder?

Tags: unity, 22.04, launcher, .desktop, sdl

I tried to create a .desktop file for my 2D shooting game made with sdl2.
the .desktop file looks like this

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=The Hunt For Red October
Comment=2D shooting game
Exec=/home/araf/Projects/The_Hunt_For_Red_October/a.out 
Icon=/home/araf/Pictures/hunt for red october intro.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

after that I checked the **Allowed executing file as program** & **Allow launching**.
but it was not executing rather a black screen popped out and instantly go away.
Later I figured out It was because that `a.out` has a dependency on a folder `/home/araf/Projects/The_Hunt_For_Red_October/assets` where all the media files are located so `a.out` file is terminating.
So, How can I include that folder with it and make it work?

Comment: Have you tried using a `Path` specification? See for example [How to create a .desktop unity launcher that starts an executable in a specific working directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191100/how-to-create-a-desktop-unity-launcher-that-starts-an-executable-in-a-specific)

Comment: Executable files don't have "dependencies" (deb packages do). If your code cannot locate the expected files, that seems like a bug in your code. Does not seem like an Ubuntu issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that problem. After seeing an answer in another question here I figured out what I missing was that I have to run the executable file in the folder where the `/home/araf/Projects/The_Hunt_For_Red_October/assets` folder is located. To do this all I needed was to add an extra line

---

```
Path=/home/araf/Projects/The_Hunt_For_Red_October/
```

---

in the .desktop file indicating the folder where the `a.out` file will run. as `assets` folder is also in the same folder so now `a.out` can access the media file from `assets`
folder and the file  executes without error.